# React + gsap + scrollMagic

Tags: reactjs, gsap, scrollmagic

Here's a codesandbox: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/greensock-and-scrollmagic-with-react-gmidc
where I use React with GSAP and ScrollMagic. BUT when I run the code on the local host there's an error that says:

```
animation.gsap.js:32 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'ScrollMagic'
    at webpackMissingModule (animation.gsap.js:32)
    at animation.gsap.js:32
    at Object../node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js (animation.gsap.js:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Module../src/index.js (import-fonts.css?480e:37)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.0 (typography.css?5564:37)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Was the package `ScrollMagic` properly added to your package.json? Are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'properly'. But both were installed through npm.

Comment: As in, is it listed in your dependencies in the package.json. also, is the folder present in the node_modules?

Comment: Yes, it is all there. There's something wrong with webpack settings. I'm about to abandon usage of scrollMagic. I have also found this: https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/issues/685

Comment: And ran eject BUT couldn't find files mentioned in the link (maybe newer version works differently).

Comment: The final answer is here: https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/issues/842

Answer (score 0):

The final working answer is here: https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/issues/842